# PHP method call reports error about it being undefined method

Tags: php, class, methods

I believe my class is correct but when I try to echo the output of the class I get an error on line 28: the line " echo 'Your full name ...." is line 28.   Any help would be nice

```
<?php

echo 'Your full name is ' . $person->retrieve_full_name() . '.';

?>
```

This is where I created the function "**retrieve_full_name**"

```
public function __retrieve_full_name() {
    $fullname = $this->firstname . ' . ' . $this->lastname;
    return $fullname;
}/* This ends the Full Name Function*/
```

the error I get is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::retrieve_full_name() in /home/mjcrawle/processlogin2.php on line 28

Comment: Where are you creating this method? How do you retrieve `$person`? Why is your method name prefixed with `__` like a magic method?

Comment: Why do you have those two underscores up there, before `retrieve`?

Comment: Interesting error. Is your class really called `stdClass`? Odd name for a personal class.

Answer (score 8):

your function is called `__retrieve_full_name`, but you call `retrieve_full_name`. notice the missing underscores.

double underscores are usually the prefix for php internal/magic functions, i would advise against using them in your function names.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate error is due to the fact that you call your method by the wrong name. And:

- don't use underscores to start a method name
- don't use underscores in method names at all, if you care for best practice, use camel casing instead `retrieveFullName()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function retrieve_full_name() {
```